# get 2nd and 3rd control points of a Cubic Bezier Curve fit in a rectangle

Tags: bezier-curve

I would like to fit a Cubic Bezier Curve in a rectangle, and wondering how to get the 2nd and 3rd control points's Y value, illustrated below:

[image]

(Sorry the rectangle is bit distorted.)
Basically, given the position of first point (x1, y1), fourth point (x4, y4), and  the height of middle point h, how can I get the y2 and y3 from this curve?

curve generated using: http://demofox.org/bezcubic.html

Thank you for any reply in advance.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\vec{B}(1/2)=\Sigma_{i=0}^3 \phi_{3,i}\vec{b_i}
$$
$$
B_y(t=1/2)=\phi_{3,0}*b_{0,y}+\phi_{3,1}*b_{1,y}+\phi_{3,2}*b_{2,y}+\phi_{3,3}*b_{3,y}\\
=\phi_{3,1}*b_{1,y}+\phi_{3,2}*b_{2,y}\\
=\binom{3}{1}t^1(1-t)^{3-1}*b_{1,y}+\binom{3}{2}t^2(1-t)^{3-2}*b_{2,y} \\
=3*(1/2)^3*b_{1,y}+3*(1/2)^3*b_{2,y}=3*(1/2)^2*b_{1,y}=50
$$
$$
b_{1,y}=b_{2,y}=200/3
$$